# Insert link in sub menu - Admin panel

Tags: admin-menu, sub-menu

Hi this is my code.

```
add_menu_page('Titlemenu', 'Titlemenu', 'read', 'a-functions', array(&$this,'namefunctions1'));
    add_submenu_page('a-functions', 'title1submenu', 'title1submenu', 'read', 'a-functions', array(&$this,'namefunctions1'));
    add_submenu_page('a-functions', 'title2submenu', 'title2submenu', 'read', 'a-functions2', array(&$this,'namefunctions2'));
```

I would like to insert a file download when user clicked in the first sub menu.

This is a classic functions for connect submenu to page to be displayed.

```
    function namefunctions1(){
    <div class="wrap">
     <?php
      include_once(dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/file.htm");
     ?>
    </div>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );
function register_my_custom_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        'My Custom Page',
        'My Custom Page',
        'manage_options',
        'my-top-level-slug',
        '',
        'dashicons-menu',
        6
    );
    add_submenu_page( 'my-top-level-slug', 'My Custom Page', 'My Custom Page',
    'manage_options', 'my-top-level-slug', 'custom_subpage_first');
    add_submenu_page( 'my-top-level-slug', 'My Custom Submenu Page 1', 'My Custom 
    Submenu Page','manage_options', 'my-secondary-slug', 'custom_subpage_second');
}

function custom_subpage_first() {
?>
    <div class="wrap">
       <?php include_once(dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/file.htm");?>
    </div>
<?php
}
function custom_subpage_second() {
?>
    <div class="wrap">
       /*Second subpage content */
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I do not understand the differences from my code. The first part of my code is include in functions namefunctionsgeneral(){}. I believe that the code to change is the one in function namefunctions1(){} because now it opens a file on the display and does not download it

Comment: You don't set parent slug of parent menu and the submenu cannot hook it.

Comment: My full function actually works. If I connect the first submenu to the function I posted, the file is shown on the display. But what I'm looking for was the download and not the opening of the file.